# How can I pass this function to another function to use the iterator of the top function?

Tags: javascript, function

So I wanted to replicate the  function/operation in Javascript.

For the people not familiar with it, here is an example:

[image: Capital sigma]

The above displayed operation would translate to Javascript code like this:

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var n = 1; n <= 10; n++) {
    sum += n ** 2;
}
```

Now I wanted to wrap it as a function, where the operation that each iteration should do would be passed as a function. So the example above would be passed like this:

```js
(1, 10, n => n ** 2)
```

```js
function (start, end, func) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        sum += func();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, the above example returns `NaN` because the variable passed doesn't use the iterator of the for-loop. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `sum += func(i)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would you mind writing that as an answer explaining why it failed?

Comment: I'd recommend just deleting the question, it's not going to have durable value to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing in the iterative value to the callback `func`:

```js
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        sum += func(i); // you have to pass it in so func knows how to func
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

But why do we want func()? This works fine too I guess. It outputs the same answer 385.

```js
function (start, end){
  let sum = 0;
for (let n = start; n <= end; n++) {
    sum += n ** 2;
}
return sum;
}
alert((1, 10));
```

Comment: The reason I want to pass it as a parameter is to do different operations with it.